# Update Panel issue on Server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-ajax

I get the following error when i deploy my application on Live server :

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
>   received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
>   error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details:
>   Error parsing near 'E'.

```
<Ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnGoTemplate" runat="server" OnClick="btnGoTemplate_Click" Text="GO "
                            Width="100" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnPreview" runat="server" Visible="false"
                                Text="Preview" OnClientClick="OpenPreview();" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" Text="Upload Status" Visible="false" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label><br />
                        <asp:Literal ID="ltrlStatus" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                    </p>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnGoTemplate" EventName="Click" />
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel3">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div id="IMGDIV" style="top: 35%; left: 50%; position: absolute; vertical-align: middle;
                    border-bottom-style: none;">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/progressbar.gif" />
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

I have been using the application on the internal server of my company and it works perfectly fine over there.I get this error when i upload it on the godaddy server.

I've tried changing the Authentication and stuff but to no avail.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks, Amee.

Comment: Check your code behind for calls to Response.Write(), comment them

Comment: There is no Response.Write() in the code-behind.

Comment: Modules?  Have you checked?  Do a Ctrl+F and search for Response.Write

Comment: Yes done that too, there is no Response.Write in my entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use tool such as Fiddler (or Firebug on Firefox) to inspect HTTP response coming from server. As such, you have a working application on some internal server, so comparing the server response (on update panel refresh) from internal server with the response from godaddy server.  Typically, HTTP response at the update panel refresh consists of various information (such as html to be refreshed, script, view-state etc) separated by pipe (|) character. So looking at response and comparing, you should able to find out the problematic characters. Then you can try to locate the code that might be inserting those characters. For example, if some piece of code is inserting an un-escaped pipe character in the response (ASP.NET will escape pipes contain within update panel html) then the update panel js parsing will fail.